# How to use node-inspector with protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, node-inspector

To use [node inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector) you normally run app using:

```
 node-inspector app.js
```

But if I'm using protractor I use the protractor binary, which in turn runs node.

I had a look at the docs for [protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/toc) and [webdriverjs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) but can't see a way to re-configure protractor (jasmine) to use the node-inspector binary.

I'm starting to look at files in the protractor folder  like `cli.js`, `runner.js`. These allow me to config node with flags, but not the actual node binary. Plus digging around in these files is starting to feel a bit hacky.

Is there a nice simple way to configure protractor to use node-inspector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the node inspector with these arguments:

```
$ npm install -g node-inspector
$ node --debug-brk node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js protractor.conf.js

# Open a new terminal and run the node inspector:
$ node-inspector

# Open your browser with this url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858
```

Comment: I suspect this is correct, but I can't quite get it to work. The node inspector launches, but does not run the webdriver etc. If I use *node*, then it does work, so I suspect I might have a problem somewhere with node-inspector. I will play with it later and mark this as the correct answer once i have verified.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, but it seems like things has changed in protractor, there is no `lib` directory, now `build` directory exists instead. Unfortunately when I do the above instruction and opening a browser on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858` it gives me an empty page, not source files at all. Any ideas ?